# How to find phone device is reachable or not using GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM and my server code is in PHP.

I am sending request to device which is not reachable in network; still I got replay as success.
Replay is `{"multicast_id":6818856885806573730,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1345696774899998%096341d0f9fd7ecd"}]}`

Is it possible to find out whether device(android phone) is reachable or not..?

Comment: Success does not mean the message was sent to phone. Message will be sent to phone when comes online.

Comment: So simple, write a code in android side....... where device will response to server for each msg which gets from GCM.

Comment: @PankajKumar : phone is not reachable, so how can it respond to request..??

Comment: Answer is in your question. Send GCM msg with no delay attribute. If you got response from device, it means your device is reachable otherwise device is not rechable.